# LavaLamp Menu issue in IE 8 - Vertical & Horizontal guideLines around the Low opacity gray oval

Tags: jquery, plugins, internet-explorer-8, menu, lavalamp

Please see the below link in both ie8 and firefox.

[LavaLamp Plugin - jQuery](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/)

orange lavalamp is ok in firefox.

but in ie8 there are some guidelines (Vertical & Horizontal guideLines Around the Low opacity gray oval... like border-right:1px solid orange; and border-bottom:1px solid orange;)

how can I remove these guidelines?
because this problem is in ie , so I can not not use firebug (firefox extension to figure out the problem)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out this problem occured because of my IE8 In Windows 7 / so i updated it to IE9 and now every thing is ok /

i test it in another IE8 in windows XP and every thing was ok / i did n't figure out what was the problem about IE8 In windows 7!